# Proof-Verification: $|xy|=|x|\cdot |y|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, absolute-value

> Proof-Verification: $|xy|=|x|\cdot |y|$

I've made a distinction in several cases. So for:

a) $x,y\geq 0 \Rightarrow x\cdot y\geq 0$:

$|x\cdot y|:=\begin{cases}x\cdot y , \quad x\cdot y \geq 0 \\ -(x\cdot y) , \quad x\cdot y <0\end{cases}$ So for $x\cdot y\geq 0$, we conclude $|x\cdot y|=x\cdot y$. Furthermore, we use the definitions for $|x|$ and $|y|$ to conclude $|x|\cdot |y|=x\cdot y|$.

b) $x,y<0 \Rightarrow x\cdot y \geq 0$:

Similarly, we have $|x\cdot y|=x\cdot y$ and by the definitions of $|x|$ and $|y|$, we have $|x|\cdot |y|=(-x)(-y)=x\cdot y$.

Hence the entire statement is proven. $\Box$

Is that a valid proof?

Comment: What about when $x$ and $y$ have different signs?

Comment: What about the  beer case $x.y<0$

Comment: Oh, you're right. I did not think about that!

Comment: In fact it can often be rather tricky just to verify rigorously that all possible cases have been considered. You need skills for doing that, as well as for handing the proofs in each individual case.

Comment: It's trivial that if either $y=0$ or $x=0$, the equality holds true. If w.l.o.g. $y>0$ and $x<0$, then $x\cdot y<0$. Hence $|x\cdot y|=-(x\cdot y)$ and $|x|\cdot |y|=-x\cdot y$. Does that complete the proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is an alternative approach:

\begin{align*}
|xy|^{2} = (xy)^{2} = x^{2}y^{2} = |x|^{2}|y|^{2} \Longleftrightarrow |xy| = |x||y|
\end{align*}

Comment: $|x|^2=x^2$ only works in $\mathbb{R}$, right? This is an interesting approach.

Comment: Yes, but in the complex case one may consider $|z|^{2} = z\overline{z}$, which leads to the same result.

Comment: So, if we consider $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|$ squaring should be quite ineffective for the RHS.

Comment: For the triangle inequality, we may consider the following reasoning
\begin{align*}
|x + y|^{2} = (x + y)^{2} = x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2] = |x|^{2} + 2xy + |y|^{2} \leq |x|^{2} + 2|x||y| + |y|^{2} = (|x|+|y|)^{2} \Longleftrightarrow |x+y| \leq |x| + |y|
\end{align*}

Comment: What about my approach?$$|x+y|\leq |x|+|y| \Longleftrightarrow |x+y|^2=x^2+2xy+y^2\leq x^2+2|x|y|+y^2=(|x|+|y|)^2$$$$x^2+2xy+y^2\leq x^2+2|x|y|+y^2 \Longleftrightarrow 2xy\leq 2|x||y|$$ Now, we're going to square it again:$$ (2xy)^2=4x^2y^2\leq 4x^2y^2$$ Now, for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$, we have $4\leq 4$ ... which is true. $x,y=0$ is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Equality true for $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Let $x, y \not =0$.

$0=(xy)^2-(xy)^2=$

$ |xy|^2-x^2y^2=|xy|^2-|x|^2|y|^2=$

$(|xy|-|x||y|)(|xy|+|x||y|)$;

For $x,y \not =0$:

We have $|xy|=|x||y|$, since $(|xy|+|x||y|) >0$.

Used: $a^2=|a|^2.$